# Passing Variable data from jframe to jpanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have a PrdList JFrame where I have a table and a button which invokes an event to get selected row from table and populate 2 text boxes in another JPanel. It is working with JFrame and populating text boxes, but with JPanel it is not working.

```
public class PrdList extends javax.swing.JFrame {

            
    public PrdList() {
        initComponents();
        tb_load();        
    }    
    
    public void tb_load(){ 
  
      try {          
          DefaultTableModel dt = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
          dt.setRowCount(0);
          
          Statement s = db.mycon().createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM product");
          
          while (rs.next()) {     
              Vector v = new Vector();
              
              v.add(rs.getString(3));
              v.add(rs.getString(2));            
              
              dt.addRow(v);     
          }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
  }
```

Table Row Selection

```
   private void jTable1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
            // TODO add your handling code here:           
           int r = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
          
           String name  = jTable1.getValueAt(r, 1).toString();
           String bcode  = jTable1.getValueAt(r, 2).toString();
```

Open JFrame

```
public Test tst = new Test();    
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    tst.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now Same thing is not working when i pass data to a JPanel text box

```
public class SaleInv extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public SaleInv() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        bcode_txt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        name_txt = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        
    public javax.swing.JTextField bcode_txt;
    public javax.swing.JTextField name_txt;
}

public SaleInv saleinv = new SaleInv();
```

Button Code to pupulate text fields in JPanel (Not working)

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     int r = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
     
      String bcode = jTable1.getValueAt(r, 0).toString();
      String name = jTable1.getValueAt(r, 1).toString();       
     saleinv.bcode_txt.setText(bcode);
     saleinv.name_txt.setText(name);
    }
```

Comment: the code you posted is either very incomplete, or won't compile. Can you show a minimal reproducible example?µ

Comment: you can't use access modifiers within methods. the code you posted won't compile. so, no, doesn't really help. Nor did you really minimize it.

Comment: I have a table in a JFrame with 2 columns. I want to pass single selected row columns barcode and product name to text fields in a JPanel. From JFrame to JFrame it is simple but doesn't work for JFrame to JPanel.

Comment: do you understand what "minimal reproducible example" means? Try with the least necessary code to reproduce the issue, and post that (exact) code. The code you posted will never compile, so there is no real wonder as to why it won't work.

Comment: It's a POS system where i want to populate product name and barcode from a popup table in JFrame. just selecting single row and click on add button to send data to Invoice Generating Screen Which is a JPanel.

Comment: Sorry I am new here. I will fix it and update.

Comment: Why are you extending ```JPanel```  in 'SaleInv' ? That's not a good name btw - it's cryptic and doesn't tell us *what* it is. 'PrdList' is not a good name either. It should be something more like ```ProductLister```

Comment: Can we pass values from jframe to jPanel ? if Possible how ?